# count number of posts (public , private , protected) by category name

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to count number of posts (public, private, protected) according to a category name suppose `blog` . To get all the posts no matter what category i used `$total_pages = wp_count_posts()->publish;`

But i cant figure out how to count number of posts for a category name `blog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-the-number-of-posts-from-a-single-category

```
<?php
$postsInCat = get_term_by('name','NAMEOFCATEGORY','category');
$postsInCat = $postsInCat->count;
echo $postsInCat;
?>
```

Or, where 17 is your category id

```
<?php
wp_list_categories('show_count=1&include=17');
?>
```